# C++ declaring and returning a variable in a function and using it in the main function

Tags: c++

I want my function sum() to add two numbers and assign the result to a variable "result". Then I want to output this result on to my main function. What am i doing wrong here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(int a,int b)
  {
   int result;
   result = a + b;
   return result;
  }

main()
{ 
   int a=2;
   int b=3;
   sum(a,b);
   printf("%d",result); 
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Think about the poor returned value. I'll be lost in this cruel world.

Comment: I believe your compiler will tell you what's wrong. Enter the error message in your favourite search engine.

Comment: @molbdnilo:  No, it won't.  Instead, the address of the `sum` function will be evaluated, and Undefined Behavior will result from trying to print that as a `%d`.

Comment: @JohnDibling I don't think that'll compile

Comment: @JohnDibling Did you misread "result" as "sum" in `main`?

Comment: @molbdnilo: Indeed I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, you could just assign the result of `sum` to a local variable and print it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(int a,int b)
  {
   int result;
   result = a + b;
   return result;
  }

main()
{ 
   int a=2;
   int b=3;
   int res=sum(a,b);
   printf("%d",res); 
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

However, if you're asking this sort of question then you're really going to struggle with C++..!

Comment: yes I know that is a possible answer but then that begs the question what is the point in using return result;?

Comment: @oliveirano25 You're using it to store the results of the calculation. You could also have said `return a+b;` if you'd wanted.

Comment: I suppose I am just struggling to understand why I have to use the return statement when it is not needed.

Comment: @oliveirano25 - the return statement is needed, it's how your function returns a value to its caller. `result` isn't needed if you put the calculcation in the return statement, but some people like to use a seperate variable for the calculation and return the variable. It's just a case of preference.

Comment: `main()` is missing the `int` return type.

Comment: okay thanks @sean that's the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

In main function put:

```
int result = sum(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a *local* variable.  It exists only within the context of the `sum()` function.

`sum()` is returning `result` by-value, meaning a copy of `result` is (potentially) being made and returned from the function.  Since you don't assign that value to anything, it dissappears.

First, do this:

```
int main()
{
  int a=2;
  int b=3;
  int c = sum(a,b);
  printf("%d",c); 
  system("PAUSE");
}
```

After running that, stop what you're doing and pick up a [good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know that I only know a little of this language, but I still can answer this question easily.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(int a,int b)
  {
   int result;
   result = a + b;
   return result;
  }

main()        // Are you serious? You forgot the int?
{ 
   int a=2;
   int b=3;
   sum(a,b);  // I'll explain this later.
   printf("%d",result); 
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

In the ***int sum()*** block, the ***int result*** is a local variable which means a variable that can only accessed by the block which is created inside. So the program will not return the result.

The ***sum(a,b)*** inside the main block shall be write like this:

```
int r = sum(a,b);
```

Note: You can replace the "r" in the code with any names you like.

And the ***main()*** part should be write like this:

```
int main() {
```

Anyway, the language you're using right now is called "C language", not C++ which it's based on that language I've talked just now. So go take a book about C++, but if you're interested in the one you're using then go find one about C language.